# Split search between python processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I currently have a large database (stored as numpy array) that I'd like to perform a search on, however due to the size I'd like to split the database into pieces and perform a search on each piece before combining the results.

I'm looking for a way to host the split database pieces on separate python processes where they will wait for a query, after which they perform the search, and send the results back to the main process.

I've tried a load of different things with the multiprocessing package, but I can't find any way to (a) keep processes alive after loading the database on them, and (b) send more commands to the same process after initialisation.

Been scratching my head about this one for several days now, so any advice would be much appreciated.

EDIT: My problem is analogous to trying to host 'web' apis in the form of python processes, and I want to be able to send and receive requests at will without reloading the database shards every time.

Comment: I personally like your question, however it may attract down votes for being too general. If this happens, I suggest try python chat group and see if they can offer you general direction on best ways first, then come back with specific programing questions on code, as a posted question, when that arises.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'll definitely give the python chat group a try later on.

Because it's quite a fundamental issue, I don't think that providing any code would help in this case.